# correctly found the angle phi (arg z)? $\left(\frac{(\sqrt2-i\sqrt2)(1-i\sqrt3)}{4}\right) $

Tags: complex-numbers

$$1)  \left(\frac{(\sqrt2-i\sqrt2)(1-i\sqrt3)}{4}\right) = \left(\frac{(\sqrt2-\sqrt2\sqrt3)+i(\sqrt2*(-\sqrt3) - \sqrt2)}{4}\right) = \left(\frac{(\sqrt2-\sqrt6)+i(-\sqrt6-\sqrt2)}{4}\right) = \left(\frac{\sqrt2-\sqrt6}{4}+\frac{i(-\sqrt6-\sqrt2)}{4}\right)$$

$$ 2)   tg  \phi = \frac{y}{x} $$
$$ 3) tg\phi = \frac{-\sqrt6-\sqrt2}{\sqrt2-\sqrt6}=\frac{(-\sqrt6-\sqrt2)(\sqrt2+\sqrt6)}{2-6}= \frac{-(\sqrt6+\sqrt2)(\sqrt2+\sqrt6)}{-4} = \frac{(\sqrt6+\sqrt2)^2}{4}=\frac{6+2\sqrt{12}+2}{4}= \frac{8+2\sqrt{12}}{4}=\frac{8+4\sqrt3}{4} = 2+\sqrt3 $$
$$4) tg\phi = 2+\sqrt3$$
$$5) \phi = arctg(2+\sqrt3)$$

Are all agreed right?

If not - tell me where the error.

And yet, how to find arg z ???

Comment: Whenever you down vote someone's question or answer. Please post reason in comment. So that user can improve himself.

Comment: @Frip $\arctan(2+\sqrt{3})$ gives an angle in the first quadrant, but the real and imaginary parts are both negative, so you have to subtract $\pi$ from it. Lookup these [computation notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)#Computation) for example.

Answer (score 1):

There is no error in above solved part.

And arg z = arctan$\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) \pm π$

As x < 0.

Also arg z = $\phi$ or $\theta$

I think that you have already found.

Also see [this link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)) for more help.

Comment: hmm, strange, other students said that they had left "good" values. Apparently I - exception :D

Comment: I don't know about others. But what you have done above is correct.

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh Don't forget the $\pm \pi$ constant. In OP's case for example $\arg z = \arctan(2+\sqrt{3}) - \pi$.

Comment: @dxiv thank you. Actually i dont know how to write +- symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\phi = \arg \cfrac{\sqrt2-i\sqrt2}{2} + \arg \cfrac{1-i\sqrt3}{2}$ both of which are easier to calculate.